# How to upgrade from Neuron 7.6 to 7.7 in Ubuntu

Tags: installation, neuron-simulator

I look for the uninstalling NEURON simulator, I found [this](https://www.neuron.yale.edu/phpBB/viewtopic.php?t=2425) post that suggest to remove `/usr/local/nrn`. Then I repeat the [same process](https://www.neuron.yale.edu/neuron/download/compile_linux) for installing the version 7.7, but the problem is I still have the previous version.
I partially followed this tutorial to install the package on Ubuntu. I use PIP instead of anaconda for installing the python packages.

Do you have any idea?

My OS is Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: You probably have to retrace the paths used during installation and remove those folders. Then follow the normal install steps to reinstall. How did u install 7.6?

Comment: I followed the [COMPILING NEURON UNDER UNIX/LINUX](https://www.neuron.yale.edu/neuron/download/compile_linux). Yes I  found `/usr/local/nrn` path but apparently it was not enough.

Comment: Also check in `/usr/local/iv`. The `~/.bashrc` file should also have a line like `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/nrn/x86_64/bin` that would need to be removed or changed.

Comment: I realized that `neuron.units` works despite the version is still 7.6.3.  I found NEURON7.6 and NEURON7.7 in dist-packages, probably that show the previous version.

Answer (score 0):

NEURON is now pip installable and it is the recommended way to install NEURON:

```
pip install NEURON
```

This will only create files under the `site-packages` folder of your Python interpreter and can be uninstalled with:

```
pip uninstall NEURON
```

Older versions of NEURON on your machine will be ignored unless you still have modifications to your `PYTHONPATH`. You can check this with `echo "My pypath is: $PYTHONPATH"` and look for any paths that seem related to NEURON and remove those.